# Operator << error when trying to write a file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm attempting to read a file (which could have any random amount of numbers, but won't have more than 500) and put it into an array.

I'm going to need to use the array later on for a number of things.

But so far this small bit of code is giving me the `no match for operator<<` in the while loop and I don't know what to do.

I'm new at this and all help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("array_pgmdata.txt");
    int index = 0;
    string myArray[index];

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {

    while (! myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      myArray[index++] << line;
    }
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myArray[index++] = line;`

Comment: Also: `while (! myfile.eof() )` is the cause of much grief. It'll _not_ be `eof` when you've read the last line - only when you try to read beynd the last line, so you'll input `line` one extra time at the end. Do: `while(getline(myfile, line)) { ` instead.

Comment: i also suggest to use a `vector<string>` and `push_back` to insert elements.

Comment: Also note that << is an output operator. You will need >> to input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You are using a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) of size 0 and step out of bounds (even index 0 would be out of bounds). Fixes and comments:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // not recommended

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("array_pgmdata.txt");
    //int index = 0;            // not needed
    //string myArray[index];    // UB - if it even compiles, it's a VLA of size 0.

    std::vector<std::string> myArray;    // use this instead to be able to grow it
                                         // dynamically

    if (myfile)                          // open and in a good state
    {
        // while (! myfile.eof() )       // It'll not be eof when you've read the last line
                                         // only when you try to read beyond the last line,
                                         // so you'll add "line" one extra time at the end
                                         // if you use that. Use this instead:
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            // myArray[index++] << line; // you have 0 elements in the array and
                                         // can't add to it in any way
            myArray.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    // print what we got

    // classic way:
    for(size_t idx=0; idx < myArray.size(); ++idx) {
        std::cout << myArray[idx] << "\n";
    }

    // using a range-based for loop
    for(const std::string& s : myArray) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    } 

    // using a range-based for loop with auto
    for(const auto& s : myArray) {               // s is a std::string& here too
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    } 
}
```

Also note that `myArray[index++] << line` is not how you assign a string to a string. `myArray[index++] = line` would have been the correct way. I suspect you used `<<` in an attempt to append the string to your VLA, but what you actually tried to use is an operator looking like this:

```
std::string& operator<<(std::string& dest, const std::string& src);
```

which does not exist (unless you add it yourself).

Comment: Might be worth commenting that even if the OP *did* have enough room in the array (he could use `string myArray[500];`), `operator <<` is not the right way to do it - he needs assignment.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Indeed. Added!

Comment: I did this and now it's saying cout wasn't declared. I put std:: before it and it still didn't work?

Comment: @LeahLeviathan You must include `<iostream>` See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! If its not too much, how would I also cout the strings and do math later on? Not very familiar with std yet

Comment: @LeahLeviathan You are welome. I'll add `cout`ing to the answer shortly. For math on them, you may need a new question since that is a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` operator is not defined on the `string` class.

You only need to do an assignment here, change `myArray[index++] << line;` to `myArray[index++] = line;`

Your instinct to use `<<` is because of it's use with `cout` or other streams like [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/). But here you just have an array of strings, so you can assign a value to an array position as you do with any other types like `int` or `char`.